# Cannot break nested functions in separate functions in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add on input method to several dom elements with same class. It is working when the `on input` function is nested inside the `each` function. When I try to separate them into two separate functions it doesnt work.

This is the working version

```
$('.textField').each(function(index, element){

    var currentField = $(this);
    var currentFieldCheckboxId = "#" + currentField.attr('name')+"Checked1";
   // Look for changes in the value
   currentField.on('input', function(event){
      // If value is NOT empty
    if ($.trim(currentField.val()) != '' ) {

        // if text fields are unchecked
        if (!$(currentFieldCheckboxId).is(":checked")){

            $(currentFieldCheckboxId).click();  
        }        
    } else {
        // If text fields are empty
        if ($(currentFieldCheckboxId).is(":checked")){ 

            $(currentFieldCheckboxId).click();
        }
    }
   });
});
```

NOT working version. It doesnt go into the not empty condition even though `.textField` isnt empty.

```
$('.textField').each(function(index, element){

    var currentField = $(this);
    var currentFieldCheckboxId = "#" + currentField.attr('name')+"Checked1";
   // Look for changes in the value
   currentField.on('input',qwer(currentFieldCheckboxId,currentField,event));
});

function qwer(currentFieldCheckboxId,currentField,event){
      // If value is NOT empty

    if ($.trim(currentField.val()) != '' ) {
        console.log("not empty field " + currentField.val());
        // if text fields are unchecked
        if (!$(currentFieldCheckboxId).is(":checked")){

            $(currentFieldCheckboxId).click();  
        }        
    } else {
        console.log("Empty field " + currentField.val());
        // If text fields are empty
        if ($(currentFieldCheckboxId).is(":checked")){ 

            $(currentFieldCheckboxId).click();
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is pass a function (a *function object*, `qwer` in your case) to another function (the `on` function). What you are actually doing is calling that function(`qwer`), and passing the result to another function (and the result is actually `undefined`, since you return nothing from `qwer`).

`qwer` <- that is the function object

`qwer(currentFieldCheckboxId,currentField,event)` <- that is the result of the function being called

You need to create another function to be called instead, if you want to pass some parameters to `qwer`.

Try this:

```
currentField.on('input', function(event) {
    qwer(currentFieldCheckboxId, currentField, event);
});
```